# jQueryUI Spinner 'undefined' error with $(this)

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to change the background colour of a spinner control when it's value is modified.

I have the following code:

```
<h2>SpinnerTest</h2>
<input id="spinner1" type="spinner" value="5" />
<input id="spinner2" type="spinner" value="10" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    //Line1:  $("input[type='spinner']").spinner({ min: 0, max: 25, stop: function () { alert(this.id); } });
    //Line2:  $("input[type='spinner']").spinner({ min: 0, max: 25, stop: function () { alert($(this).id); } });
</script>
```

When I use Line1 I get an alert with the correct spinner control ID.  However, when I use Line2 I get an alert with 'undefined'.

Ultimately, I want to call toggleClass() on the spinner element.  Hence why I'm trying to use $(this).

I'm relatively new to jQuery - could someone help explain why $(this) doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.id`](http://api.jquery.com/?s=.id) is not a valid property for the jquery object.   To get the id of an element, use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/): `$(this).attr("id")`.

The `.attr()` method, if only one parameter is supplied, gets the corresponding attribute's value.  If a second parameter is supplied, it changes that value to the second parameter supplied.

Comment: I said I was new to it.  :-)